# Como acessar a propriedade data-weekday do elemento div com javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como acessar a propriedade data-weekday do elemento div com javascript?

```
<div style="display: none;" id="weekday" data-weekday="7"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```js
const weekDay = document.getElementById('weekday').dataset.weekday;
console.log(weekDay); // 7
```

```html
<div style="display: none;" id="weekday" data-weekday="7"></div>
```

Ou ler o atributo diretamente:

```js
const weekDay = document.getElementById('weekday').getAttribute('data-weekday');
console.log(weekDay); // 7
```

```html
<div style="display: none;" id="weekday" data-weekday="7"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar um atributo da sua div basta usar [`getAttribute("data-weekday");`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) especificado no w3schools. Segue a demo.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("weekday").getAttribute("data-weekday");
alert(x);
```

```html
<div style="display: none;" id="weekday" data-weekday="7"></div>
```

Com [Jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_get.asp)

```js
var x = $("#weekday").attr("data-weekday");
alert(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: none;" id="weekday" data-weekday="7"></div>
```